# implant a comparator to string array in java

Tags: java, comparator

Suppose I have a method  - `private static void sort(String[] arr)` 
Now I want to sort this array using the comparator - `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`
Is it possible to set this as the default comparator to the String arr before passing 
the argument to this function `sort`. It's like I wont have to change anything inside the sort function to modify its behavior. It's like the comparator gets implanted into
the arr

Comment: A string array doesn't hold anything but strings

Comment: No, an array of strings cannot have its own "default comparator".

Comment: No.  There is no (good) way to associate a default `Comparator` with a `String[]`

Comment: not sure if that is what you mean, but you can have the method accept a comparator as an optional argument through overloading

Comment: Could there be some way of making an anonymous class objects out of the string array which has the comparator?

Comment: What's wrong with the Arrays#sort method that takes an array and a comparator?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are meant to be basic, simple containers.

If you want more features, use a class from the [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

If your elements are distinct (no duplicates need be tracked), use a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) implementation. Java bundles two. One is [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html).

```
NavigableSet< String > navSet = new TreeSet<>() ;
```

By default, the navigable set uses the “natural order” of your objects, by calling their `compareTo` method. Alternatively, you can pass a `Comparator` to the constructor, to be used for sorting.

In your case the `String` class carries a `Comparator` implementation as a constant: [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) .

```
NavigableSet< String > navSet = new TreeSet<>( String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER ) ;
```

**Caveat:** That comparator does *not* account for locale in sorting your strings. For locale-savvy sorting, use a [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html) instead.

You said:

> It's like I wont have to change anything inside the sort function to modify its behavior. It's like the comparator gets implanted into the arr

That is exactly what you get by specifying a `Comparator` for  a collection class.